# replace ALL pixels if Red Channel NOT found in the list

Tags: python, numpy

I have a colored image and a mask in a numPy value as defined below:

```
img = cv2.imread(path)
mask = [13 16 17 23 24 25 29 30 31 100]
```

Now, I want to change ALL pixels to 0 or Black if my colored image the Red channel value IS NOT in my mask.  I can do this by doing a loop, but I want to do this in a numPyish way.  Is this possible?

Comment: Basically, if the red channel in your image has any value other than the ones in your mask, you make the entire image black?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.isin` to check.

```
img = cv2.imread(path)
mask = np.array([13, 16, 17, 23, 24, 25, 29, 30, 31, 100])
reds = np.isin(img[:,:,2],mask)
```

OpenCV loads images in the bgr format, meaning that red is the last channel. `np.isin` returns you a boolean array of shape (HxW), telling you which red pixels are in the mask and which ones aren't. You can then do a simple check if all pixels are True or not.

```
if np.prod(reds):
    img[:]=0
```